# How to create a custom control factory method

Tags: c#, factory

I have a skinnable Control library that was loads control settings/properties from external xml files.
The `Xml` classes are in a seperate project as these will be used in a skin editor application, now the question, The controls accept an xml object in the constructor to build the `Control` but I need to find a nice way to create each control.

Xml class example:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(XmlButton))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(XmlGroup))]
[XmlType(TypeName="Control")]
public class XmlControl
{
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Height { get; set; }
 ...
```

and derived types per control type

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "Button")]
public class XmlButton : XmlControl
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

Control classes

```
public class GUIControl : GUI3DBase
{
    public GUIControl(XmlControl skinXml)
    {
        SkinXml = skinXml;
...

public class GUIButton : GUIControl, IActionControl
{
    public GUIButton(XmlControl skinXml) : base(skinXml)
    {
    }
...
```

Now this is where I need help, at the moment I have a Method to create controls based on the xml object passed in.

```
    public static GUIControl CreateControl<T>(T skinXml) where T : XmlControl
    {
        if (skinXml is XmlButton)
        {
            return new GUIButton(skinXml);
        }
        else if  (skinXml is XmlGroup)
        {
            return new GUIGroup(skinXml);
        }
        ....
```

I have about 30 controls and the "if ladder" is growing fast and I feel like I am missing a simple way to create thes controls withou needing to check the xml object type then create the corresponding control type.

I can't add a `Type` property in the Xml object as that would create circular dependency.

Any help on a good factory method or new stucture layout would be awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way to do this with all your ideas and a little reflection, not sure if its the best way but it works nicly and adding a new skinnable control only requires a new xml object and an attribute on the control class.

Attribute Class

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class XmlControlTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    protected Type xmlType;

    public XmlControlTypeAttribute(Type xmlType)
    {
        this.xmlType = xmlType;
    }

    public Type XmlType
    {
        get { return this.xmlType; }
    }
}
```

Control:

```
[XmlControlType(typeof(XmlButton))]
public class GUIButton : GUIControl, IActionControl
{
    public GUIButton(XmlControl skinXml) : base(skinXml)
    {
    }
    ....
}
```

Factory method:

```
public static GUIControl CreateControl2<T>(T skinXml) where T : XmlControl
{
    var controlType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes
        .Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(GUIControl) && t.GetCustomAttribute<XmlControlTypeAttribute>().XmlType.Equals(typeof(T)))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return (GUIControl)Activator.CreateInstance(controlType, new[] { skinXml }, null);
}
```

Thanks for all the ideas the helped heaps, I will leave this question open a bit longer incase somome has a better solution than this.

Comment: I think you've found a great solution. It makes sense to associate the actual control with the class which defines its configuration. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `IDictionary<Type, Func<XmlControl, GUIControl>>` would help. Something like this:

```cs
private static Dictionary<Type, Func<XmlControl, GUIControl>> _dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<XmlControl, GUIControl>>()
                                                                                    {
                                                                                        {typeof (XmlControlImpl), x => new GUIControl(x)},
                                                                                        {typeof (XmlGroup), x => new GUIGroup(x)},
                                                                                    }; 

public static GUIControl CreateControl<T>(T skinXml) where T : XmlControl
{
    Func<XmlControl, GUIControl> builder;
    if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out builder))
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("");

    return builder(skinXml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to add an abstract method to `XmlControl`:

```
public abstract class XmlControl
{
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public abstract Type ControlType();
```

override it in each implementation eg:

```
public class XmlButton : XmlControl
{
    public string Label { get; set; } 

    public override Type ControlType(){ return typeof(GUIButton); }
}
```

And then use reflection in the Factory method to construct the right class:

```
public static GUIControl CreateControl<T>(T skinXml) where T : XmlControl
{
    return (GUIControl)Activator.CreateInstance(skinXml.ControlType(),
                                     new[]{skinXml},null);
}
```

Comment: I can't add a Type property in the Xml object as that would create circular dependency, the xml and control libarys are seperate projects, Control class can know about xml class, but xml class must be independant of controls project

Comment: In which case I think your best bet is @AlexanderBalte solution. A lookup dictionary.

Comment: perhaps your answer and his together, I like the idea of using `Activator.CreateInstance` as its nice and clean, and I guess I could make the dictionary<Type,Type> as this could be reused for other situations where I need to match the 2 types together